# Android application can't launch

Tags: android, eclipse, launch

I have made this app but when i try to launch it a message pops saying application has stopped.I really can't find any mistake in the code..
  This is the code it is just many ImageButtons :

```
package com.fanis.math;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyResistance extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
View b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b10, b11, b12;
Button bok, bclear;
TextView t;
int k = -1;
int[] ar = new int[4];
double n = 0;
double multi=0;
String nString;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.resistance);

    b1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.im1);
    b2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.im2);
    b3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.im3);
    b4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.im4);
    b5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.im5);
    b6 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.im6);
    b7 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.im7);
    b8 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.im8);
    b9 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.im9);
    b10 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.im10);
    b11 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.im11);
    b12 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.im12);
    bok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok);
    bclear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clear);
    t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    b2.setOnClickListener(this);
    b3.setOnClickListener(this);
    b4.setOnClickListener(this);
    b5.setOnClickListener(this);
    b6.setOnClickListener(this);
    b7.setOnClickListener(this);
    b8.setOnClickListener(this);
    b9.setOnClickListener(this);
    b10.setOnClickListener(this);
    b11.setOnClickListener(this);
    b12.setOnClickListener(this);
    bok.setOnClickListener(this);
    bclear.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.im1:
        k += 1;
        ar[k] = 0; // dianisma pou krataei kathe psifio
        break;
    case R.id.im2:
        k += 1;
        ar[k] = 1;
        break;
    case R.id.im3:
        k += 1;
        ar[k] = 2;
        break;
    case R.id.im4:
        k += 1;
        ar[k] = 3;
        break;
    case R.id.im5:
        k += 1;
        ar[k] = 4;
        break;
    case R.id.im6:
        k += 1;
        ar[k] = 5;
        break;
    case R.id.im7:
        k += 1;
        ar[k] = 6;
        break;
    case R.id.im8:
        k += 1;
        ar[k] = 7;
        break;
    case R.id.im9:
        k += 1;
        ar[k] = 8;
        break;
    case R.id.im10:
        k += 1;
        ar[k] = 9;
        break;
    case R.id.im11:
        k += 1;
        multi = 0.01;
        break;
    case R.id.im12:
        k += 1;
        multi = 0.1;
        break;
    case R.id.ok:
        for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
            n = n + ar[i - 1] * Math.pow(10, k - i);
        }
        if (multi == 0) {
            multi = Math.pow(10, ar[k]);
        }
        n = n * multi;
        nString = String.valueOf(n) + "" + "Ω";
        t.setText(nString);
        break;
    case R.id.clear:
        t.setText("");
        n = 0;
        k = -1;
        multi=0;
    }

}
```

}
  And this is the manifest

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.fanis.math"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MyResistance"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

This is layout though i don't think it is the reason i can't launch the app..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="40dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/im1"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:src="@drawable/black" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/im2"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:src="@drawable/brown" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/im3"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:src="@drawable/red" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/im4"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:src="@drawable/orange" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/im5"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:src="@drawable/yellow" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/im6"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:src="@drawable/green" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/im7"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:src="@drawable/blue" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/im8"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:src="@drawable/purple" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/im9"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:src="@drawable/grey" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/im10"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:src="@drawable/white" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/im11"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:src="@drawable/silver" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/im12"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:src="@drawable/gold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ok"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:text="Ok" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clear"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:text="Clear" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My logcat:

```
 04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847): Process: com.fanis.math, PID: 847
04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847): java.lang.RuntimeException:           Unable to start activity        ComponentInfo{com.fanis.math/com.fanis.math.MyResistance}:    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line  #44: Error inflating class  <unknown>
   04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847):   at    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
   04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
  04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #44: Error inflating class <unknown>
04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)     04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at com.fanis.math.MyResistance.onCreate(MyResistance.java:25)
04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  ... 11 more
04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  ... 26 more
04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:587)
04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:422)
04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2110)
04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:129)
04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:87)
04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:83)
04-11 04:29:17.420: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  ... 29 more
```

Comment: Where's your logcat?

Comment: try again after clean and rebuild the project, then post your log if still crashes.

Comment: dubug your app then you can get where is error

Comment: Sir, give me details on your  XML file line #44:, or in short you are having  `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`.. Your `ImageButton` images are pretty huge..

Comment: Thanks!!the problem was the resolution of images!!

Answer (score 0):

Change this line :

```
View b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b10, b11, b12;
```

to:

```
ImageButton b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b10, b11, b12;
```

Comment: `View` is parent class of `ImageButton`, `View parent = (ImageButton) child;`  this would not cause error.

Comment: This is not the problem because they where ImageButtons at first place and after it didn't work i changed them to view..